# Use filedata instead of file attribute to pass data

Tags: javascript, webgl, vtk, xtk

I'm trying to render vtk objects which are send from a webserver directly on the client using XTK without storing them to the disk. According to the [XTK Documentation](http://api.goxtk.com/mesh.html) I just have to pass the vtk file as string into X.Mesh.filedata, but it just doesn't display anything when I'm trying to do that.

I want to do something like this:

```
var data = recieveVTKFileAsStringFromServer();
var r = new X.renderer3D();
r.init();

// create a mesh from a .vtk file
var dataset = new X.mesh();
// dataset.file = 'someFile.vtk';
dataset.filedata = data;

// add the object
r.add(dataset);

// .. and render it
r.render();
```

When I load the file from the file everything works just fine, setting it using filedata doesn't. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also came up with the similar scenario to load the binary data directly using filedata instead of setting file attribute. I did this by passing dummy name in a file attribute along with actual binary data set in filedata and everything works fine.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/test.nii', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            var r = new X.renderer2D();
            r.container = 'myImg';
            r.orientation = 'Z';
            r.init();
            volume = new X.volume();
            volume.file = "abc.nii";
            volume.filedata = this.response;
            r.add(volume);
            r.render();
        }
    };
```